# how to create a table for the league

Tags: c++, struct

I am creating a C++ project and it's a console application and I have to show premiere league table with using structs , arrays ,file stream and input and output I made a struct but I don't have and idea what to do next and  it has to be on console not GUI. I tried making a struct but don't know what to do

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
struct standing 
{
int position;
char name[20];
int matches;
int win;
int draw;
int lose;
int GD;
int points;
};
```

Comment: Now make a list containing objects of this structure. By the way, this site is not meant for absolute beginners. You should ask your teacher, or your colleagues, or search the internet for answers, before you come here.

Comment: @Salman Mohamed Check my answer below, I hope it solves your problem

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
struct Team
{
private:
    int rank;
    std::string name;
    int matches;
    int win;
    int draw;
    int lose;
    int GD;
    int points;
};

struct League
{
private:
    std::vector<team> teams;
}
```

Say we have these two structs. One struct for a team the other one for the whole league.

We can now add some constructors for Team struct (trivial) and League struct and public methods.

```cpp
struct League
{
public:
    void addTeam(Team team_)
    {
        teams.push_back(team_);
    };
    Team getChampion()
    {
        // simple algo to get winning team
    }
    std::pair<Team, Team> getRegulated(){
        // simple algo to get regulated teams
    };

private:
    std::vector<team> teams;
};
```

https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/